# elasticsearch 7 nest aggregation text keyword error

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I Have an index with the following mappings:

```
{
    "winnings": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "handId": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "playerId": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "float"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

generated from the class:

```
public class ElasticWinnings
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid HandId { get; set; }
        public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I created that in nest with the ConnectionSettings:

```
.DefaultMappingFor<ElasticWinnings>(u =>
    u.IndexName("winnings")
         .IdProperty(x => x.Id)
 );
```

when I try and run the following query:

```
var result = _client.Search<ElasticWinnings>(s =>
    s.Aggregations(a =>
            a.Terms("term_Agg", t =>
                t.Field(f => f.PlayerId)
                    .Aggregations(aa =>
                        aa.Sum("sum", sum => 
                            sum.Field(f => f.Value))
                        )
            ))
  );
```

I get a 400 back, with the error:

```
type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default
```

It creates this query:

```
{  
   "aggs":{  
      "term_Agg":{  
         "aggs":{  
            "sum":{  
               "sum":{  
                  "field":"value"
               }
            }
         },
         "terms":{  
            "field":"playerId"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If I changed that query to:

```
{  
   "aggs":{  
      "term_Agg":{  
         "aggs":{  
            "sum":{  
               "sum":{  
                  "field":"value"
               }
            }
         },
         "terms":{  
            "field":"playerId.keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and used that in postman, it works.

I am not sure why it is not putting the `.keyword` into the query.  Is it the way the nest client is configured, the indicies or the query?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your query a little bit to tell NEST to use `keyword` field instead of `text`, you can do this with `.Suffix` extension method. [Link to docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/property-inference.html).

```
var result = _client.Search<ElasticWinnings>(s =>
    s.Aggregations(a =>
            a.Terms("term_Agg", t =>
                t.Field(f => f.PlayerId.Suffix("keyword"))
                    .Aggregations(aa =>
                        aa.Sum("sum", sum => 
                            sum.Field(f => f.Value))
                        )
            ))
  );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I ended up finding a different solution, but its great to know about the extensions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Even after roughly 3 years, this answer is still helpful because the NEST documentation is a bit awful around this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add `[Keyword]` to the `PlayerId` property in `ElasticWinnings` class.

I kept the `.DefaultMappingFor<ElasticWinnings>(u => u.IndexName("winnings")` in the creation of the `ConnectionSettings` class, but added this before the Elastic client is returned:

```
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

client.Indices.Create("winnings", c =>
    c.Map<ElasticWinnings>(m => m.AutoMap())
);
```

Without adding the section above, it did not apply the attributes.  This changed my mappings (`http://localhost:9200/winnings/_mappings`) to

```
{
    "winnings": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "handId": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "playerId": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "double"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the docs about setting up the mappings https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html